# Apache CXF Eclipse plugin, workspace creation "Cant canonicalize system path: {0}"

Tags: maven, cxf, eclipse-wtp

I'm attempting to follow the directions at http://cxf.apache.org/setting-up-eclipse.html to set up Apache CXF v2.7.7 (set up with Maven 3.1.0) for use in Eclipse WTP (Kepler Service Release 1) on my win7 64bit laptop. I was able to add all three plugins(CheckStyle, PMD, Subversion) successfully to Eclipse, but when it came to creating a workspace, I ran into two issues:

1.) The direction to "First [check out CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/source-repository.html) from Subversion." Makes no sense to me. The page directs me to three different variations of "svn co {URL}" commands, but I have no svn batch or executable that is apparent, since all I did was install plug-ins. No idea what I'm supposed to do here.

2.) The "mvn -Pfastinstall" went fine, but the "mvn -Psetup.eclipse" command conked out at a databinding step with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9
:eclipse (setup.eclipse.project) on project cxf-systests-databinding: Cant canon
icalize system path: {0}: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax i
s incorrect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (setup.eclipse.project)
 on project cxf-systests-databinding: Cant canonicalize system path: {0}
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
357)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cant canonicalize sys
tem path: {0}
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.IdeUtils.getCanonicalPath(IdeUtils.java:1
47)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.IdeUtils.toRelativeAndFixSeparator(IdeUti
ls.java:591)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.extractResourceDirs(Ecl
ipsePlugin.java:1787)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.buildDirectoryList(Ecli
psePlugin.java:1684)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.createEclipseWriterConf
ig(EclipsePlugin.java:1359)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.writeConfiguration(Ecli
psePlugin.java:1178)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.AbstractIdeSupportMojo.execute(AbstractId
eSupportMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label sy
ntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.IdeUtils.getCanonicalPath(IdeUtils.java:1
43)
        ... 27 more
```

There are canonicalize errors like this that point to an issue in a pom file that is using "${basedir}" in a way that isn't referring to the pom file, but I don't see this.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this? This is a completely new installation of Eclipse WTP and following the directions to get Apache CXF up and running. Nothing has been customized, I've just been doing exactly what they're telling me to so I can just write some basic web service code.

Comment: Can you add maven cxf plugin config snippet?

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific?

Comment: I would prefer to see your pom.xml

Comment: It's too large to post, but it is the included pom.xml with apache cxf 2.7.7 - I haven't modified anything. Is there something in it I can look up or cut out and paste here for you to see?

Answer (score 0):

I've no Idea about the page you are referring. However if your starting with CXF Here are 2 easiest ways to generate JAXB, service and client classes from WSDL, its every easy as well to generate wsdl using bottom up approach.

**First approach**

1. New Project -> Dynamic project
2. Select the server you want use.
3. In configuration select custom and select modify and ad cxf and jaxb facet.
4. on click next till you need to add cxf libraries( which you need to download).
5. click finish.
6. Copy your wsdl to the project.
7. select other and select web service
8. select topdown approach and add select you wsdl.
9. select web service runtime as cxf
10. Remaining steps are pretty much self explanatory.

**Other way is from maven.**

1. Add cxf dependencies refer (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html you can use 2.7.6 version).
2. Add Spring dependencies
3. Add plugin to generate jaxb and other cxf classes, wsdl2java refer(http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)
4. In the below code I've added profile code-gen which I run to generate the classes using goal generate resources.

   code-gen
           
               local

   ```
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                       <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                       <version>1.0.0</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                               <pluginExecutions>
                                   <pluginExecution>
                                       <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                           <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                           <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                                           <versionRange>[2.7,)</versionRange>
                                           <goals>
                                               <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                           </goals>
                                       </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                       <action>
                                           <execute />
                                       </action>
                                   </pluginExecution>
                               </pluginExecutions>
                           </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>

               </plugins>
           </pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                   <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>generate-sources</id>
                           <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                           <configuration>
                               <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                               <wsdlOptions>
                                   <wsdlOption>
                                       <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
                                       <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                       <extraargs>
                                           <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                           <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                           <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                           <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                                       </extraargs>
                                   </wsdlOption>
                               </wsdlOptions>
                           </configuration>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>

           </plugins>
       </build>
   </profile>
   ```

The advantage in the first method is that eclipse generates even cxf-bean.xml where as second approach doesn't generate beans.xml. So what I prefer is that if for the first time I will generate using the first method. on sub sequence run if there is any wsdl change I run the maven way.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the CXF to be used in the first place. The page I am referring to are the directions for setting up CXF for Eclipse. If there is an easier way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: I would suggest to use the first approach which s much more simpler, once you are comfortable with cxf components, you can go with maven

Comment: The CXF libraries I downloaded (Apache CXF Runtime) require compilation. Is there another set that will work on Apache Tomcat and use jsr101 (JAX-WS) that comes compiled?

Comment: Here is the link http://cxf.apache.org/download.html to download libraries. You add the library in project facet, cxf framework. No need of compilation of libraries. It worked fine for me in tomcat